# SQL Query - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The following query is giving an error at
'CASE WHEN NOT LIKE' (Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE')

```
SELECT     
 TimeStamp, 
 TimeStampNS, 
 ISNULL(TagName, 'NoTag') AS TagName, 
 Message, 
 ConditionName, 
 ISNULL(TagName, 'NoTag') + '.' + ConditionName AS Source, 
 CENTUMMsgId, 
 StationName,  
 ISNULL(AlarmLevel,5) AS AlarmLevel,
 ActiveTime, 
 ActorID, 
 ISNULL(AlarmOff,0) AS AlarmOff,
 CASE WHEN  NOT LIKE '% ACK%' AND CENTUMMsgId IN (4353, 4355, 4609) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RaiseAll, 
    CASE WHEN  LIKE '% ACK%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Acknowledge, 
    CASE WHEN CENTUMMsgId IN (4354, 4356, 4358, 4614) AND Message NOT LIKE '% ACK%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Normal, 
 PlantHierarchy, 
 'EXAOPC' AS SourceType
FROM QHistorianData.dbo.vEXAOPCCSProcessAlarm
```

Do you guys know what's going on... I think I have eveything correct there.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you missed the attribute name here:

```
CASE WHEN <ATTRIBUTE-NAME> NOT LIKE '% ACK%' AND CENTUMMsgId IN (4353, 4355, 4609) THEN 1   ELSE 0 END AS RaiseAll, 
CASE WHEN  <ATTRIBUTE-NAME> LIKE '% ACK%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Acknowledge, 
CASE WHEN CENTUMMsgId ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN **[MissingExpression]** NOT LIKE '% ACK%' AND CENTUMMsgId IN (4353, 4355, 4609) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RaiseAll, 
CASE WHEN **[MissingExpression]** LIKE '% ACK%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Acknowledge, 
CASE WHEN CENTUMMsgId IN (4354, 4356, 4358, 4614) AND Message NOT LIKE '% ACK%' THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS Normal, 
PlantHierarchy,
```

You missed to define the column you want to compare with like

Answer (score 1):

You are missing column name/Expression After `WHEN`.

```
CASE WHEN 'EXPRESSION'  NOT LIKE '% ACK%' 
     AND CENTUMMsgId IN (4353, 4355, 4609) 
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RaiseAll,
```